# Cannot use String.Empty as a default value for an optional parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

I am reading **Effective C#** by Bill Wagner. In *Item 14 - Minimize Duplicate Initialization Logic*, he shows the following example of using the new optional parameters feature in a constructor:

`public MyClass(int initialCount = 0, string name = "")`

Notice that he used `""` instead of `string.Empty`.
He comments:

> You'll note [in an example above] that the second constructor specified "" for the default value on the *name* parameter, rather than the more customary `string.Empty`. That's because `string.Empty` is not a compile-time constant. It is a static property defined in the string class. Because it is not a compile constant, you cannot use it for the default value for a parameter.

If we cannot use the `string.Empty` static in all situations, then doesn't that defeat the purpose of it? I thought that we would use it to be sure that we have a system-independent means of referring to the empty string. Is my understanding wrong? Thanks.

UPDATE
Just a follow up comment. According to MSDN:

> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition. If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used. **Default values must be constants.**

Then we aren't be able to use `System.Environment.NewLine` either, or use newly instantiated objects as default values. I haven't used VS2010 yet, and this is disappointing!

Comment: I am not aware of any differences between how empty strings are represented on different platforms.  It's not like newline.

Comment: Right, I was thinking that, so then is it just that it looks nicer in code?

Comment: The CLR and not the 'System' is the determining factor as to whether "" is an empty string or not. So I think you could safely assume the "" is a system-independent way of refering to a string on a compliant CLR implementation.

Comment: "system-independent"? er, as opposed to the system-specific ""? (???)

Comment: According to MSDN: The value of this field is the zero-length string, "".

so then it obviously has nothing to do with platform independence, as many people are pointing out. Yet it still seems people don't really know why it should be used!

Comment: We joked once how much code would break if Microsoft pulled a joke and changed the value of string.Empty to something else :) And I personally use it heavily, except where I cant. I just think its cleaner, though thats an opinion

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the way newlines are represented in strings does *not* differ between platforms; it's always "\n". What differs is how it's represented in *files*, and you can get any line-ending style in a file on any system, so it gets autodetected and handled in file reading code, much like character encoding. The System.Environment.NewLine constant is a recommendation for what to write to files, but just writing "\n" is safe if you do it consistently.

Comment: @jimrandomh are you sure about that? Maybe it's just my Visual Studio debugger window/watches part, but when i query what Environment.Newline is, it is more often than not this instead: ``\n\r`` ? But you're sure that if i just use \n it'll pick it up and run with it... say if i want to use it as a delimiter to split a string, picked up from reading a file?

Comment: @jimrandomh "I'd just like to point out that the way newlines are represented in strings does not differ between platforms" -- that's completely irrelevant to this discussion.  "What differs is how it's represented in files" -- which is what the value of System.Environment.NewLine is. "you can get any line-ending style in a file on any system" -- again irrelevant (and not true, unless you think the only systems are Windows systems) ... System.Environment.NewLine is the default representation, which is *the* representation when *writing*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't String.Empty a constant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought an equality operator (==) for a string first checked that they were referencing the same object before doing a character by character comparison so using string.Empty gave a performance boost.  
"" looks like hard coded special value to me - that I try to avoid.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As of the C# 2.0 compiler, there is very little point to `String.Empty` anyway, and in fact in many cases it's a pessimisation, since the compiler can inline some references to `""` but can't do the same with `String.Empty`.

In C# 1.1 it was useful to avoid creating lots of independent objects all containing the empty string, but those days are gone.  `""` works just fine.

Comment: Even in .NET 1.1 it wouldn't create "lots" of independent objects. I can't remember the details of the differences between 1.1 and 2.0 in this respect, but it's not like string literal interning was only introduced in 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I've had a look around and I haven't found a good summary of the changes in C# 2.0, although I'm sure I've read one previously.  I did find a StackOverflow answer from 2008 with some links to more technical information.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and

Comment: I'll give this a nod, though I dislike saying there is little point to string.Empty as I use it quite heavily. I find it just looks cleaner, though that is my personal opinion. There are many places string.Empty cannot be use, and I have no problem using "" in those cases

Comment: I've used string.Empty only because it was the "recommended" thing to do, but I never really liked it.  The literal "" seemed straight-forward and clear and with string interning, it's economical too.

Comment: I've found that it's much easier to quickly identify an empty string with String.Empty than looking twice at "" to ensure it didn't have an apostrophe or something like that hidden in it.  +1 for the explanation though.

Comment: +1 Chris. Also in VS, you really can't do a search on usages of "" (other than doing the standard Find which will also bring back every text match, including comments and markup).  You can do a search on code specific usages with string.Empty.

Answer (score 55):

There's nothing to stop you from defining your own constant for the empty string if you really want to use it as an optional parameter value:

```
const string String_Empty = "";

public static void PrintString(string s = String_Empty)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

[As an aside, one reason to prefer `String.Empty` over `""` in general, that hasn't been mentioned in the other answers, is that there are various Unicode characters (zero-width joiners, etc.) that are effectively invisible to the naked eye. So something that looks like `""` isn't necessarily the empty string, whereas with `String.Empty` you know exactly what you're using. I recognise this isn't a common source of bugs, but it is possible.]

Comment: There are also invisible identifier characters, so something that looks like String_Empty isn't necessarily. The Unicode standard has a largely ignored chapter on security considerations.

Answer (score 26):

From the original question:

> I thought that we would use it to be sure that we have a system-independent means of referring to the empty string.

In what way can the empty string vary from system to system? It's always a string with no characters! I'd be *really* scared if I ever found an implementation where `string.Empty == ""` returned false :) This is *not* the same as something like `Environment.NewLine`.

From Counter Terrorist's bounty post:

> I want String.Empty can be used as a default parameter in the next C# release. :D

Well that's certainly not going to happen.

While I would personally have liked a very different defaulting mechanism too, the way optional parameters work has been in .NET since the start - and it always means embedding a constant into the metadata, so that the calling code can copy that constant into the call site if no corresponding argument is provided.

With `string.Empty` it's *really* pointless - using `""` will do what you want; is it *that* painful to use the string literal? (I use the literal everywhere - I never use `string.Empty` - but that's a different argument.)

That's what surprises me about this question - the complaint revolves around something which *doesn't* actually cause a real problem. It's for more important in cases where you want the default to be computed at execution time because it might actually vary. For example, I could imagine cases where you want to be able to call a method with a `DateTime` parameter and have it default to "the current time". At the moment, the only vaguely elegant workaround I know for that is:

```
public void RecordTime(string message, DateTime? dateTime = null)
{
    var realDateTime = dateTime ?? DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

... but that's not always appropriate.

In conclusion:

- I very much doubt that this will ever be part of C#
- For `string.Empty` it's pointless anyway
- For other values which really *don't* always have the same value, it really *can* be a pain

Comment: This is actually a good way of fixing the problem. The same thing can be used to carry/set other device dependent variables like ``Environment.Newline`` .. The only thing missing from your example would be a check on the variable for null, and throwing an exception back to the developer telling him that while it's nullable, it's not accepted. ``if(dateTime == null){ throw new ArgumentException("The dateTime parameter must be set. Nullable type used for device independent variable set.");}`` or something like that. But i really like this! Any other caveats to doing it your way?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv: You don't want it being null to be an error - the whole point is that when it's null, you compute a default. The caveat is that it doesn't allow null to be passed through as a valid value in itself.

Comment: You are completely right about that. My bad. -- And yes, that would be the only real caveat wouldn't it... that's not too bad. Again: i really like this solution! :) Thanks for posting it! :)

Comment: But using 'string.Empty` reads so much nicer than "" string literal. Do others agree with string.Empty being better from a readability perspective?

Comment: @jbob77435: I absolutely disagree - I find `""` to be far more readable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I suppose this issue is subjective. But as you taught me almost everything I know via your excellent book C# in Depth, I do find myself questioning my taste in this matter.

Answer (score 7):

I never use string.Empty, I can't see the point of it. Maybe it makes it easier for people that are really new to programming, but I doubt it's useful even for that.

Comment: Maybe it prevents confusing `""` and `" "`, but I can't say that `" "` is all that common.

Comment: I'd suggest that anyone that can't tell the difference between those needs either better glasses or to lower the resolution of their screen. I've got bad eyesight and I can't recall ever making that mistake (and I do have to work with a lot of code that contains both of that).

Comment: string.Empty is useful to find out the exact intention of the programmer. "" does not tell anything about the intention, what if the programmer intention was to initialize the variable like this "lol" but forgot...in this case there are endless possibilities and string,Empty comes handy and does a better job

Answer (score 4):

I think the idea behind string.Empty is it enhances readability.  It is not like newline where there is any difference between how it is represented on different platforms.  It's ashame it can't be used in a default parameter.  However, it will not cause any issues if you port between Windows and something like Mono on Linux.

Comment: I think you're probably right that the point is that some people consider `String.Empty` more readable . . . personally though, I think that's a little nutty. `""` is probably the most common string there is and everyone has seen it a billion times, so how is it unreadable? `String.Empty` is about as useful as if there were an `Int32.Zero`.

Answer (score 3):

As a FYI, it looks like the same constraint is imposed on values passed to attribute constructors - they must be constant. Since string.empty is defined as :

```
public static readonly string Empty
```

rather than an actual constant, it cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

I use `string.Empty` purely for readability.

If someone else needs to read/change my code later they know that I meant to check for or set something to an empty string. Using just `""` can sometimes cause bugs and confusion because I may have just forgot to put the string that I wanted in there.

**For example:**

```
if(someString == string.Empty)
{

}
```

vs

```
if(someString == "")
{

}
```

The first `if` statement just seems so much more deliberate and readable to me. Because this is just a preference though, I really do not see the train-smash in having to use `""` instead of `string.Empty`.