# Why can't I use DateTime.MinValue and int.MinValue as optional values in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, optional-parameters

Can someone explain what's wrong with the following method signature written using C# 4.0?

```
public void Test(string arg1 = string.Empty, DateTime arg2 = DateTime.MinValue){}
```

I understand the difference between "" and string.Empty in terms of compile time checking but surely the way that optional parameters have been implemented in C# 4.0 is pretty inadequate if you can't declare a reasonable value type null style comparisson?

Comment: If arg2 = DateTime.MinValue, would it always be this constant value? It might be redundant in the eyes of the compiler?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use String.Empty as a default value for an optional parameter in C# - then what's the point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701314/cannot-use-string-empty-as-a-default-value-for-an-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` aren't compile time-constants -- they're `readonly` fields that are initialized at run time by `DateTime`'s static constructor.

See the difference between `const` fields (which are compile-time constants) and `readonly` fields (which aren't): [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

Comment: Tim, sorry, I should have been clearer. I understand that they arent' design time constants but surely the language design time support should be able to dynamically consider this scenario?

Comment: Optional parameters require you to supply compile-time constants. You'd have to ask the language designers why, but fundamentally .NET only supports a small set of data types for compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as parameter values only literal values, constant values and new object instances.