# Why do optional parameters in C# 4.0 require compile-time constants?

Tags: c#, .net, optional-parameters

Also is there a way to use run-time values for optional method parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use String.Empty as a default value for an optional parameter in C# - then what's the point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701314/cannot-use-string-empty-as-a-default-value-for-an-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Optional parameters are required to be constants because they are written out as values of an attribute.  Hence they inherit all of the restrictions that an attribute value has.

There is no way to directly encode a runtime value.  However you can get close with the following pattern

```
public void MyApi(SomeType type = null) {
  type = type ?? new SomeType();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a neat trick. Out of curiosity, do you know why they are implemented using attributes? I assume to reuse what's already in the framework?

Comment: @Joan IIRC it is done with attributes because that's how other languages (VB.Net) do it and hence it provides compatibility with them.

Comment: @Joan: By using attributes, they don't break languages that don't have this feature.  Remember, everything in .NET gets compiled into a form that needs to be language neutral...  Attributes are a clean way to handle optional parameters in a specific language, without requiring breaking changes to other .NET languages.

Comment: @Jared: Thanks, but now I realize, if the trick you showed wouldn't work for value types, or reference types where you legitimately want to pass null, right?

Comment: @Reed: Thanks that's a good point. But if it was an extended feature of IL, would it still break it for other languages? Like say something extra that only C# outputs to IL?

Comment: @Joan: That would require a CLR change just to support this feature - the way they did it, it matched the existing VB implementation, has no impact on other languages, and "just works"...

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. That makes sense. They just went with the easiest route then.

Answer (score 5):

Optional parameters are compiled into the assembly and as such (just like anything that is designated as `const`) they must be a compile-time constant.

And no, you cannot use execution-time values as optional parameters.

Comment: Thanks but can't it compile with a reference to a run-time reference? So say something like: this.Filename, etc within the same class?

Answer (score 5):

Optional parameters are determined at *compile time*, and substituted into the method if you call a method with too few parameters.  They are handled via adding an attribute to the parameter in the method's IL.

As such, they need to be fully resolved at compile time (both for creation, since they're an attribute, but also when used).  There is no way to use runtime values for optional method parameters.