# Can using string.Empty be harmful?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, compiler-construction, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

I just stumbled over the following sentence in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701314/cannot-use-string-empty-as-a-default-value-for-an-optional-parameter-in-c-then/2701349#2701349):

> As of the C# 2.0 compiler, there is
>   very little point to `String.Empty`
>   anyway, and in fact in many cases it's
>   a pessimisation, since the compiler
>   can inline some references to `""`  but
>   can't do the same with `String.Empty`.

Is this statement true? Should we therefore always use `""` instead of `string.Empty`?

**Please note**: I'm not asking about any coding styleguide (which is easier to read). I'd like to know if there is a functional difference (e.g. inlining).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to make a distinction or worry about it either way.  It's a waste of engineering/thinking time to consider the problem - there is no impact either way. (What I mean is: "it doesn't matter").  Is it harmful?  Of course not, isn't that obvious?

Comment: If you look at the answer a little bellow (on that link) you will notice that the generated IL is almost the same and the generated assembly is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this statement true?

The point of interning is to share references to save memory and reduce comparison time (reference comparison is blazing fast). As `String.Empty` is a `static readonly` field on the `String` class, all uses of it already share the same reference. Therefore, `String.Empty` is already effectively interned (note that I said "effectively" and note, in particular, that it's not interned with uses of `""` in your assembly).

> Should we therefore always use `""` instead of `string.Empty`?

Personally I find `String.Empty` to be vastly more readable. Use what you prefer. If there are any performance differences it is seriously unlikely to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I also tend to use `String.Empty`. If nothing else, it prevents subtle bugs coming from `""` and `" "` looking sort of alike at a quick glance.

Comment: Is interning the same or related to inlining?

Comment: @M4N: I suspect the author of that quote meant "interning."

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine (ReferenceEquals ("", string.Empty) ? "Same Reference" : "Different Reference");
// Prints "Same Reference"
```

Looks like it's purely preference (at least on the Microsoft versions of the CLR).  Does anyone know about MONO?

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always use the one that's easier to read. The potential will rarely matter in practice.

IMO `""` is easier/clearer to read. But others prefer `String.Empty`. So it's mainly a matter of style.

The performance part you quotes seems plausible. `""` is a compile-time constant and will be interned. `String.Empty` is a static readonly field. Unless the C# compiler programmers took special care to replace `String.Empty` with `""` at compile-time it might be slightly slower in some rare scenarios. All uses of `""` will share the same instance, and I expect `String.Empty` to point to the very same instance.

If you combine `""` with other constants in a way that the compiler understands it might evaluate the whole expression at compile-time. It probably won't do that with `String.Empty` which is no constant. But I can't think of an example that makes sense in practice.

Example:

```
string s = ""+"A"+""+"B"+"";
```

might be faster than:

```
string s = string.Empty+"A"+string.Empty+"B"+string.Empty;
```

But of course any sane person would write:

```
string s = "AB";
```

But it's possible that the C# programmers added a special case for `String.Empty` that replaces it with `""` in which case there would be no difference at all.

Comment: Note: the question is not about readability.

Comment: You edited that in after I wrote the part about readability.

Comment: Yes that's why I added the note here as well :-) The question is only about the quoted statement.