# String.Empty in Switch/case statement generate a compiler error

Tags: c#, string, compiler-errors, switch-statement

If `String.Empty` is as good as `""`, then how come the compiler throws up with string.Empty in the `case` statement? Nothing can be more constant than `string.Empty` in my view. Anyone know?  Thanks!

```
switch (filter)
            {
     case string.Empty:  // Compiler error "A constant value is expected"

                break;

                case "":  // It's Okay.
                    break;

            }
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701314/cannot-use-string-empty-as-a-default-value-for-an-optional-parameter

Comment: @blacai Thanks!  That was a good read!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like this instead:

```
switch(filter ?? String.Empty)
```

`string.Empty` is a read-only field whereas `""` is a compile time constant. You can also go through a article here on Code Project [String.Empty Internals](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20677/String-Empty-Internals)

```
//The Empty constant holds the empty string value.
//We need to call the String constructor so that the compiler doesn't
//mark this as a literal.
//Marking this as a literal would mean that it doesn't show up as a field 
//which we can access from native.

public static readonly String Empty = "";
```

**On a side note:**

You will also see this issue when you are providing the default parameter value inside your method(C# 4.0):

```
void myMethod(string filter = string.Empty){}
```

The above will result in a compile time error as the default value needs to be a constant.

Comment: Thanks Rahul.  But I was just wondering how come we can't use string.Empty.  It's kind of strange to me.

Comment: @Zuzlx:- As far as I know `string.Empty` is a read-only field whereas `""` is a compile time constant.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again. We can discover that there is water on Mars but jolly we can't use `string.Empty` testing for for `""`  Sad state of affairs

Answer (score 4):

The reason is: you cannot use `readonly` values in case: consider the following scenario:

```
public string MyProperty { get; } // is a read-only property of my class
switch (filter)
{
    case MyProperty:  // wont compile this since it is read only
    break;
          // rest of statements in Switch
}
```

As you said `string.Empty` is equivalent to `""`, here I can prove this with the same example of a switch statement:

```
string filter = string.Empty;
switch (filter)
{
   case "":  // It's Okay.
   break;
    //rest of  statements in Switch
}
```

Then the only reason it won't allow `string.Empty` in case it is read-only, the switch won't allow read-only values in its case.