# C# 4.0 - How to Handle Optional String Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

This code is not valid:

```
private void Foo(string optionalString = string.Empty)
{
   // do foo.
}
```

But this code is:

```
private void Foo(string optionalString = "")
{
   // do foo.
}
```

Why? Because string.Empty is a readonly field, not a constant, and defaults for optional parameters must be a compile-time constant.

So, onto my question... (well, concern)

This is what i've had to do:

```
private const string emptyString = "";

private void Foo(string optionalString = emptyString)
{
   // do foo.
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalString))
      // etc
}
```

How do you guys handle optional string parameters?

Why can they not make [String.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) a compile-time constant?

Comment: why not stick with ""?  That's all I ever do, but that's also because I don't understand the advantage of using String.Empty.  Must be a unicode thing, but I don't ever have to worry about that (at least not yet... yikes)

Comment: I am confused why you think you *need* to do this.  I consider `nullString` a confusing name, because at first glance I would be inclined to think it was `null`, not `""`.  As for your final question, see [
Why isn't String.Empty a constant?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant).  @Dave, there's no Unicode thing, here.  `""` is fine; see also [
In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or).

Comment: @prateeksaluja20 - what does the title/tags mention???

Comment: @STW - why did you remove my edit??

Comment: It didn't add to the question--and the answer's weren't attacking you, they may have been blunt, but your original question wasn't exactly neutral.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ummm... what's wrong with string optionalParm = "" again?  Why is that bad?  Do you really think you need a symbolic constant for an empty string in this case?  How about this then?

```
const int Zero = 0;

void SomeMethod(int optional = Zero) { }
```

Does that seem at all silly to you?

Comment: Agreed, i named that badly. I just got so used to using string.empty for most string operations, that when i started using Optional Params, i didnt like the fact i had to go back to "". Guess ill stick with "".

Comment: Facetious mode: If you want people to read your code as 'zero' rather than 'nought' then maybe it's OK

Comment: Why such a rude response? The OP had a legitimate question.

Answer (score 8):

if you don't like "" value you can use default(string).
I played with it and it is allowed.

```
private static void foo(string param = default(string)) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)) // or param != default(string)
        Console.WriteLine(param);
}
```

Comment: The default(string) value is null, not empty string.

Comment: @allonhadaya, specifying a non-`null` default value doesn’t prevent anyone from explicitly passing `null` :-p.

Comment: @binki, I'm not sure I understand your point. What do you mean?

Comment: @allonhadaya, I forget. Maybe I was trying to say that the default of `null` makes more sense than specifying a parameter default of `""`. In some cases you do want to distinguish between the empty string and `null` and having a default value of `null` implies that your method handles an explicitly-specified `null` value nicely. Though this has more to do with the OP’s choice to use `""` instead of `null`…

Comment: @binki, Aha - Functions get messy when the choice of default value is a member of the expected domain; it can then no longer be used as a reliable signal. `null` tends to be a better signal than `""` because it is the only member of the `string` type which implies 'no value'.

Answer (score 5):

[Code Analysis warning 1026](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182135.aspx) says not to use optional parameters. It's better style to use overload methods, like this:

```
private void Foo()
{
   Foo(string.Empty);
}
private void Foo(string optionalString)
{
   // do foo.
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalString))
      // etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle them is with:

```
private void Foo(string optionalString = "")
{
   // do foo.
}
```

So you can't use String.Empty.  Everyone recognizes "", but if I found `optionalString = nullString` I wouldn't be sure what to think.  ***If nothing else, name the thing `emptyString`--it's not null!***

Comment: Agreed, i named that badly. I just got so used to using string.empty for most string operations, that when i started using Optional Params, i didnt like the fact i had to go back to "". Guess ill stick with "".

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question.

`Why can they not make String.Empty a compile-time constant?`

Here is the disassemble code via Reflector of String.cs in mscorlib.dll

```
public static readonly Empty;
static String()
{
    Empty = "";
    WhitespaceChars = new char[] { 
        '\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', ' ', '\x0085', '\x00a0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 
        ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '​', '\u2028', '\u2029', '　', ''
     };
}
```

So in windows platform, string.Empty is exactly "". But do you know, Martian have a different definition for Empty and WhitespaceChars in their OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to play lose and treat null, "", and whitespace characters to be the same, then you can default to `null`. This becomes very handy when user name and password are optional fields due to a possibility of trusted connection to a db. You could change this logic to reset strings to `null` and thus modify the assert and the `if`. The important part is having a consistent convention.

```
private void RunSql(string serverName, string databaseName, string userName = null, string password = null)
{
    userName = Strip(userName);
    password = Strip(password);

    // The `MsTest` assert - works in both `Debug` and `Release` modes.
    Assert.AreEqual<bool>(
        userName == String.Empty,
        password == String.Empty,
        "User name and password should be either both empty or both non-empty!");
   Assert.IsFalse(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serverName));
   Assert.IsFalse(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(databaseName));

   var cmdBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   cmdBuilder.AppendFormat("sqlcmd -E -S {0} -d {1} ", serverName, databaseName);
   if (userName.Length > 0)
   {
       cmdBuilder.AppendFormat("-U {0} -P {1} ", userName, password);
   }

   // Complete the command string.
   // Run the executable.
}

// Cannot think of a good name. Emptify? MakeNullIfEmpty?
private string Strip(string source)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    return source;
}
```