# In C#, why is string.Empty a field instead of a constant?

Tags: c#, .net, string, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't String.Empty a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant)

I can use "" but not string.Empty when specifying default values for method arguments in C# 4.0. This would make sense if string.Empty could mean something other than "", but it is a constant, it is just not declared as const.

Was this just a mistake on Microsoft's part that they can't clean up with const because it is too core to the language and would be a breaking change? Or was there a legitimate reason for making this a populated field instead of a const in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be a literal, or it wouldn't be accessible from the native half of `String`.

The comments (in the reference source) say:

```
// The Empty constant holds the empty string value.
//We need to call the String constructor so that the compiler doesn't mark this as a literal.
//Marking this as a literal would mean that it doesn't show up as a field which we can access
//from native. 
public static readonly String Empty = "";
```

Comment: Interestingly, the comments say "we need to call the string constructor" but the code does not call the string constructor.