# Why is string.Empty readonly?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't String.Empty a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant)

...and not `const`?

I know its probably a useless question, but I'm sort of curious on the reasoning behind this one. An empty `string` is an empty `string` so I do not foresee many chances of `string.Empty` being anything else than `""`. So why make it `readonly`?

Is there any other benefit I'm missing in not making it `const`?

Comment: Values marked `static` are still open to being modified, no? The intent with `readonly` is clear: no modification possible.

Comment: Technically it isn't... http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/The-Disgruntled-Bomb.aspx?pg=2 Has a very nasty piece of code for disgruntled employees to leave lying around

Comment: woops yeah sorry, I meant const. Anyhow sorry for the duplicate, I should have checked before.

Answer (score 3):

It IS static.

```
public static readonly string Empty;
```

Comment: so what? aren't const's static on the class too? Doesnt answer.

Answer (score 0):

Readonly prevents it from being changed.  Perhaps you mean "why isn't it a const"?

Comment: Yes he meant it in the question. Doesn't answer