# What are "native" and "literal" keywords

Tags: c#, .net, keyword

I see many times using **native** and **literals** "keywords" in C# articles. What do they mean?

examples:

[`string.Empty` article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/StringEmpty.aspx):

> The Empty constant holds the empty string value. We need to call the
>   String constructor so that the compiler doesn't mark this as a
>   **literal**. Marking this as a **literal** would mean that it doesn't show up
>   as a field  which we can access from **native**.

[C# vs Java Wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java)

> Simple/primitive types
>    Both languages support a number of built-in
>   types which are copied and passed by value rather than by reference.
>   Java calls these types primitive types, while they are called simple
>   types in C#. The simple/primitive types typically have **native** support
>   from the underlying processor architecture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the C# spec section 2.4.4:

> A **literal** is a source code representation of a value.

So for example there are literals for strings and numbers:

```
string x = "hello";
int y = 10;
```

... but C# has no literal syntax for dates and times; you'd have to use:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 11);
```

As for native support - there are different levels of "native" here, but as far as C# is concerned, I'd usually consider it type-specific support in whatever output format is used. So for example, there *are* IL instructions to deal with the binary floating point types (`float`, `double`) but when the C# compiler emits code dealing with `decimal` values, it has to call the operators declared in `System.Decimal`. I'd therefore consider that `float` and `double` have *native* support in IL, but `decimal` doesn't.

(It would be possible to write a C# compiler targeting a different platform which *did* have native support for `decimal` - or which didn't have native support for `float` and `double`, for example. Unlikely, but possible.)

Then when the IL is being run in an execution engine, that will be running on top of "real" native code - x86 for example - which can have specific support for certain types. That's another level of "native". For example, if someone came up with a new version of IL which included native support for `decimal`, that wouldn't mean that the CPUs themselves suddenly gained native support.

Comment: could you please be kind and update the post with explanation to this sentence according to your answer: "Marking this as a **literal** would mean that it doesn't show up as a field which we can access from **native**"

Comment: @gdoron: I don't know - it doesn't make much sense to me, to be honest. I believe it's talking about access from native code, rather than support for native types, but I don't know the details behind the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The quote from the string.Empty article looks like a classic case of code comments getting out of sync with their associated code.  The comment says "we're calling the constructor rather than using a literal" but the code doesn't call the constructor: it uses the literal.  The moral of the story: don't let your confusion make you think you've misunderstood, because the comment is confusing.

There is a lot of misinformation out there regarding string.Empty, since it is a bit of an odd case.  The expression new string() == "" is generally expected to be false, since the new operator is generally expected to create a new instance.  But it doesn't create a new instance, it returns the instance in the intern pool, which its the same as "", so the expression is true.

I suspect that the "native" in "access from native" refers to native code (the second meaning of "native" that Jon Skeet mentioned).  But if I were you, I wouldn't spend too much time on that article.  It's far too concerned with abstract theory that anyway seems incorrect.

If you want to know whether string.Empty is more or less efficient than "", compile two versions of the same function, and check the IL.  If the IL differs, run some performance tests.

Comment: Thanks for the salvation from those comment and article!

Comment: The comment isn't out dated.  It means that the CLASS constructor will be called.  Initializing static fields and properties implicitly creates a class constructor that is automatically called the first time the class is referenced.