# lock ExtractToDirectory only runs once

Tags: c#, zip, race-condition

This function takes a few seconds to run locally.  It unpacks a zip file onto the local server and is called before serving individual files in the zip.  It should only run once if the extracted folder does not exist.

```
internal static void Init(string releaseName)
{
    var unpackedFolderDirectory = Settings.Editor.FilesRootFolder + releaseName + "\\";
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(unpackedFolderDirectory);
    if (dirInfo.Exists) return;

    lock ("UnpackLock")
    {
        dirInfo.Refresh();
        if (dirInfo.Exists) return;

        // Unpack all
        var bytes = getBytesFromAzure();
        using var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms))
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(unpackedFolderDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

If I make multiple requests to this function, some of them return the error:

```
The file 'C:\SomeFolder\SomeSubFolder\SomeFile.png' already exists.
On line -> archive.ExtractToDirectory(unpackedFolderDirectory);
```

I am expecting the `archive.ExtractToDirectory(unpackedFolderDirectory);` to only execute once, but it appears to be running multiple times.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some race condition here I'm not spotting?

Comment: Not sure if locking on a string is a good idea.

Comment: @Fildor thank you!  Locking on a static object fixes the issue.  It would be great to understand why the code I posted doesn't work.  Is it because the string instance is non static?

Comment: It basically comes down to how strings work in C#/.Net. All the specialities with interning, caching etc. So, while it's the same string all the time, it doesn't mean that for the system it's the identical "object" / reference. You can even end up clogging other parts of the software if you were to use the same string to lock elsewhere.

Comment: See also: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/lockchoice.html Paragraph 4 : _"One other practice occasionally seen is that of locking on string literals, for example declaring string someLock = "Lock guarding some data"; and then locking on someLock. This has the same problem as the other locking strategies, due to string interning - if two classes both use the same string literal, they'll end up using references to the same string, so they'll be sharing a lock without realising it. If you really want to make a lock with a description, you can always create your own Lock class. ... "_

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to use a string as a lock object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804879/is-it-ok-to-use-a-string-as-a-lock-object) / [Why only literal strings saved in the intern pool by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509035/why-only-literal-strings-saved-in-the-intern-pool-by-default) These don't explain why the `lock ("UnpackLock")` doesn't work in your case though.