# Are Strings Interned When Used As Return Values in Switch Statements?

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement, c#-9.0, string-interning

Say I write a switch statement where the return value is a string. Are the strings that this switch statements return interned (since they may be referenced many times)?

Say we have an enumeration called `DogBreed`.

```cs
private static string DogBreedToString(DogBreed dogBreed)
{
   return dogBreed switch
   {
       DogBreed.GoldenRetriever => "golden_retriever",
       _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Breed ({dogBreed}) is unsupported"),
   };
}
```

In other words, if this gets called two times from two different parts of the code, will both parts of the code receive a reference to the **same** instance of `"golden_retriever"`?

Comment: The compiler has an optimizer and the optimizer should merge the strings.  A string is a class object which is difficult to merge.  c# does not use pointers so depending where in the code the strings are located will determine if the strings get merged.

Comment: Strings from literals are interned by default. Strings from `new String(someChars)` is not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why only literal strings saved in the intern pool by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509035/why-only-literal-strings-saved-in-the-intern-pool-by-default)

Comment: If you're not sure if two strings were interned to the same memory location, you can always check them using [Reference.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-6.0).

Comment: For what it's worth, that's not A _switch statement_, it's a _switch expression_. Statements don't return anything