# String.Empty is not a constant value?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t String.Empty a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant)

To make my code more readable I tried to assign `String.Empty` to a constant value:

```
const string PLATYPUS_ADDED_AND_ACCEPTED = string.Empty;
if (false) { }
else
{
    toolTip = PLATYPUS_ADDED_AND_ACCEPTED;
}
```

but I get `"the expression being added must be constant"`

Isn't `String.Empty` always the same thing? That seems pretty constant to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.Empty` is a [readonly field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.empty.aspx), not a constant.

The compiler has no way to know this will always be the same value.

Comment: Actually, Tim's answer is better as Tim pointed to the explanation of this choice by Microsoft.