# Why can't String.Empty be used when creating a const string variable?

Tags: c#

I often use `String.Empty` for a placeholder, which equates to `""`.  So my question, why does a `const` not like `String.Empty`?  They compile identically.

```
// Good
private const string example = "";

// Bad
private const string example = String.Empty;
```

What in `String.Empty` makes it not able to be used with a `const`.

Comment: @Greg Because it doesn't evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: I would suspect it's because `Empty` isn't *itself* a constant, so as far as the compiler is concerned it *could* resolve to anything.  And a `const` needs to guarantee at compile time what it's value will be.  The literal `""` provides that guarantee.

Comment: @Greg As far as the compiler is concerned, any string value.  It has no idea at compile time.

Comment: @Lucas There are millions of ways to subtly break code when you have a malicious developer.  String.Empty is no exception to this; a malicious developer could just as easily edit the string that it refers to to a non-empty string (yes, it would *absolutely* be possible, even through managed code).  There's virtually no way to defend code against a malicious developer editing the source code; it's not even something you can meaningfully attempt to defend against.

Comment: We're using String.Empty instead of "". It just looks better IMHO.

Comment: Discussion about preferences between  [`String.Empty` vs. `""`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and-empty-string)... This question seem to be just about "why readonly can't be use as const" (approximately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const) OR ["why `String.Empty` is not const"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant). Some clarification from Greg may help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.Empty` is *not* a constant it's only `readonly` field. And since it's `readonly` field (which is *not* known on compile time) it can't be assigned to a constant.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,c9f70a27facb27cf

```
...
//We need to call the String constructor so that the compiler doesn't mark this as a literal.
//Marking this as a literal would mean that it doesn't show up as a field which we can access 
//from native.
public static readonly String Empty;
```