# When using inlinedata is it possible to use string.empty?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit.net

I was wondering while writing some tests if it was possible to use the by @microsoft declared string.isempty when using xUnit tests. (See below)

I'm a programming student and my teachers recommended using @microsofts already defined methods and consts when possible.

I've tried it but it didn't seemed to work, so thought I might have done something wrong.

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(string.Empty)]
[InlineData(null)]
[InlineData("        ")]
[InlineData(" ")]
[InlineData(" someRandomText")]
// ... 
public void SetEmailaddress_WrongEmail_IllegalArgumentException(string data) // type of method that is being test, what kind of test, the expected outcome
   {
      //Assert
      Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => _l.Emailaddress = data);
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Greetingz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with tests and everything to do with attributes. Attributes must be a compile time constant.

You can go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant) question to find out why `string.empty` is not considered a constant vs `""`

Comment: C# has no concept of "decorators". It has **attributes**.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Potato potato, but updated all the same.

Comment: Something a newbie can search on and find useful information if they want to read more, something a newbie will find no or close to no results for if searching for more useful information... If you're trying to be a clear communicator, one of the easiest ways to do that is to use the *right names for things*.

Comment: gilliduck damien_the_unbeliever thank you, much clearer now

Comment: @Agrendallan if this helps and answers your question, you can click the checkmark button to accept this as the answer.