# Difference between string.Empty and ""

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Is there any difference in c# between the following declarations...

```
private string m_port = string.Empty;
```

or...

```
private string m_port = "";
```

Is it just coding standard that makes it look neater?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just coding standard...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.empty%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, but looks better.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is one of semantics - `string.Emtpy` says that you meant to have an empty string. `""` might be a mistake (`" "`, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Since String.Empty is an instance it should remove the overhead of the object creation, however I think a parser should be smart enough to figure this out.

All string literals is also pulled from an object pool I believe, so the object creation might not even take place.