# Why do we need to use String.Empty instead of using ""?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

I got the warning suggesting me to use String.Empty instead of empty string "". I can't figure out why. If you do, please share!

Comment: [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Comment: Check the links... [String.Empty vs ""](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx) [c# string.Empty vs ""](http://forums.asp.net/p/977917/1250790.aspx) [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)