# difference between string.empty and ""

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012072501/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx)

> As David implies, there difference
> between String.Empty and “” are pretty
> small, but there is a difference.  “”
> actually creates an object, it will
> likely be pulled out of the string
> intern pool, but still… while
> String.Empty creates no object… so if
> you are really looking for ultimately
> in memory efficiency, I suggest
> String.Empty.  However, you should
> keep in mind the difference is so
> trival you will like never see it in
> your code…

**Note:**

> ...you should
> keep in mind the difference is so
> trival you will like never see it...