# if else string is null

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have two text box. If 1 of the textbox.text is empty, the MessageBox would show to prompt user that they did not enter the fields completely. However it does not work...

This is the code:

```
private void tab1nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text == null) || (MasterbuildpropertiespathTextBox.Text == null))
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("You have not specified the paths completely!");

    }
    else
    {
        Tabitem2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 1;

    }
}
```

I tried to add breakpoint to examine the immediate values. When either one of the Textbox.Text is empty, the immediate value is "" respectively. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: The `Text` in a `TextBox` will never be `null`.  It will always have some string value.  In the case of an empty `TextBox`, the `Text` property will contain the empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) and [`null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da(v=VS.100).aspx) **are not the same**.
In your case of an empty `TextBox` it will always be `String.Empty`.

You should check for `Empty` with the [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text)
```

or

```
AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text == String.Emtpy
AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text == ""
```

See also this SO question/answers: [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or "" ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Comment: actually you can just test AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text.Length > 0 since .Text will never be null and all you'll check is to see if text contains something.

Answer (score 6):

try `string.IsNullOrEmpty(AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text)`

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` might be better.

Comment: Note that IsNullOrWhiteSpace was not available until .NET 4.0

Comment: @Xavinou depending on the version of BCL that might or might not be available

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between an empty string and a null string.

A empty textbox will have a empty string, so you have to check `...Text == ""` or `...Text == string.Empty` instead of `...Text == null`.

Answer (score 0):

Null and Empty Strings are two different concepts. Null is a reference which does not point to any object in memory. Empty string is a zero-length string object, that is created on the heap. If you check for not null, this only checks that the reference is pointing to an object and nothing else. For empty string you should include a seperate check, or just use string.IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for empty strings. The code you have 'AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text == null' checks for null reference. Use this instead.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(AntcbatchpathTextBox.Text)
```