# Why is it recommended to check string length to determine emptiness?

Tags: c#

Often, people say that it is better to say `s.Length == 0` instead of `s == ""`. But it seems like this would be a microoptimization that also makes it harder to read. Also, ten million of the former as opposed to the latter save at best 60 ms.

Is there a reason that I'm missing, such as if perhaps `s.Length == 0` actually conveys the intent better? Or is it common to need to compare many strings for emptiness?

EDIT: I know about IsNullOrEmpty, but when people answer the question, they often mention that length checking is better than comparing to the empty string.

EDIT2: Not asking about the best way to do this which would be IsNullOrEmpty for both cases, but I'm asking why it is that a non-negligible minority insist that length checking is superior. I'm assuming that they have some good reasons for saying so, and want to know what they are.

EDIT3: As stated in the beginning, I do know that one is faster than the other. The question is, is that the reason people recommend it? Some timings showed that this did not lead to significant differences.

Comment: I would rather use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` in case I trip on null reference exceptions... (accidentally swallowed my comment)

Comment: Who says "it is recommended"?  Its actually IsNullOrEmpty/IsNullOrWhitespace that is recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, it's essentially a micro-optimisation.  Testing the length does keep FxCop / Code Analysis quiet though - and the justification is performance, as [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279.aspx).

As for which is more readable, that's subjective, and I'm sure any developer would understand either.  Since they are semantically different (`s.Length == 0` throws if s is null, whereas `s == ""` doesn't), readability isn't the only criterion to consider.

In cases where you're not certain the string is not null, `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` might be even more readable (i.e. expressive of your intention).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is by doing `s == ""` you are doing a string comparison which is slower than the other way (`s.Length == 0`)

Comment: Not very significantly; .net strings know their length; this is checked first

Comment: I would be very shocked if the JIT'd code is not the same for both checks.

Comment: It seems like the JIT'd code would at least have to be somewhat different, as the first would return false and the second would throw an exception in the case of a null string.

Answer (score 1):

In most of my code, using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` (in .NET 4) are easier to read and more specifically do what I really need done.

Answer (score 0):

s == string.Empty is an alternate to s.length == 0.

My guess on why s == "" is not recommended is that "" would create a immutable string on heap. Just for comparison, you may not want to create a string object. Anyhow someone may validate my statment.

Comment: I was under the impression that almost all empty strings in code shared the same instance.

Comment: "" is an immutable string literal. You can see that ("") would have all the properties that a string variable can hold. That's the reason I wrote that you are creating a string object for your comparison.

Comment: I get that, but it seems like all of the ("") would refer to the same string, via interning (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Comment: Hmmm. That's a news to me. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't checked the official csc, but Mono's compiler (dmcs) actually does `ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty` before `call bool string::op_Equality(string, string)`, even if `""` was used in source code. So no unneeded string instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

String values comparision is slower than numeric values comparision.

I would use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) in your case.

Answer (score 0):

not all dot net strings are interned at runtime
that means that s.Length == 0 would be faster in those cases
as it avoids an actual string comparison which results if one of two strings is not interned
[See String.IsInterned() on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx)