# string ss=""; vs string ss = string.empty; vs string=null; in c#

Tags: c#

I am confused with below code. Which one is better to use. Can you explain the differences between them.

I am C# learner...

- `string ss = "";`
- `string ss = string.Empty;`
- `string = null;`

Comment: which is better depends very much on the context you are using this code in.

Comment: Can you correct all spelling and grammar errors in your question?

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty(ss) is specially designed for that kind of comparisons

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: There are no comparisons in that question.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. The question might lack effort or even be a duplicate, but I don't think that it is "too broad".

Comment: The one that is better is the one that is *correct*. Since we don't know what you're trying to do, it's impossible to say which one is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `""` and `String.Empty` are synonyms. They both refer to an **empty string**. Which one to use is a matter of preference. The following question contains various opinions on that topic:

   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or "" to intitialize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263191/87698)
2. `null` refers to a **null reference**. The difference between an empty string and a null reference is detailed in the following question:

   [string.Empty vs null.Which one do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6689876/87698)