# C# - Use of unassigned local variable 'stringnamehere'

Tags: c#

Here's my code:

```
        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        string drivenames;
        for (int i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
        drivenames = drives[i].Name;
        MessageBox.Show(drivenames); // --> For debug purposes only
        strCmdText = "del /f /s " + drivenames + "*.sfk";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }
```

I'm trying to get the drive letters on the computer to a string, however, when I'm trying to use the string, it says Use of unassigned local variable 'drivenames'. What's the problem here?

Comment: This is why you always use `{}` brackets.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with @JeroenVannevel - It NEVER appears to me to be worth it getting rid of them, even when it's simply a one-line statement under a simple `if`

Comment: I think he wants the Messagebox in the loop also, so he definitely needs the brackets.

Comment: @DeeMac Same thoughts. I've been coding for years, never wrote a single block without `{}`

Comment: I disagree.  Single-statement `if`s and `while` loops are completely fine.  Just don't put the statement on the next line, or use a coding tool that will fix indent errors.

Comment: @CleverNeologism It is not about indentation. It is all about avoiding careless mistakes.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's exactly about indentation.  It's almost impossible to make this mistake in properly indented code, and given VS will be able to automatically indent any compilable program correctly, there is no need whatsoever to add lots of superfluous brackets to prevent this type of error.

Comment: @Sriram Thus the option of not putting the single statement following the if on the next line.  Unless you are in the habit of putting multiple statements on a single line, you can't carelessly add a second statement, thinking it's part of your `if` statement.  Thus, your code is pretty well segregated: all single-statement `if` statements are one line without braces (and looking at code, it's obvious if there's something after the `if`), all multistatement `if`s are multiline and use braces (of course).  It's hard to make a mistake, because it won't "look right".

Answer (score 7):

If `drives.Count()` is 0 the loop will not be entered. Then the variable is still unassigned. That's why the compiler doesn't like `MessageBox.Show(drivenames)`.

You could assign `""` or `null`:

```
string drivenames = "";
// ...
```

The compiler just wants to help you to avoid bugs.

If you instead want to show the `MessageBox` for every drive you have to move it into the loop as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25310124/284240) has shown. You could also use this LINQ query which does not need an explicit loop:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    string drivenames = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, drives.Select(d => d.Name));
    MessageBox.Show(drivenames); 
}
```

Comment: If I edit my 'string drivenames' to 'string drivenames = null;', the MessageBox shows up G:\ , but I actually don't even have a drive called G:\.

Comment: @user3669879: have you used the debugger?

Comment: And what about the case when I have to enter the drive letters into the command prompt for a command? For instance, I want to run "del /f /s DRIVELETTERSHERE*.filetypehere"?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you want to show a messagebox for each drive.  If that's the case, you want something more like this:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    string drivenames = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
    {
        drivenames = drives[i].Name;
        MessageBox.Show(drivenames); // --> For debug purposes only
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Based on comments, this could be dratically simplified to:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        // todo: write some code here
        MessageBox.Show(drive);
    }
}
```

Isn't that easier to read?

Comment: I much personally prefer this, using an empty string, over assigning a  null value. It will prevent any unexpected behavior associated with the null value.

Comment: And what about the case when I have to enter the drive letters into the command prompt for a command? For instance, I want to run "del /f /s DRIVELETTERSHERE\*.filetypehere"?

Comment: @Tyress There is no need for the variable to exist outside of the scope of the loop in the first place.  The variable shouldn't exist *at all* when it doesn't have a valid value, rather than having some "preferred" default value.  Scoping the variable appropriately, or removing it entirely, is far safer.

Comment: Also, Use `foreach` wherever you can. Here there is no need of `for` loop. Use `Array.Length` instead of `Count()` extension method.

Comment: @Tyress: what is unexpected, that it is still `null` after the loop? Then it is good to know, isn't it? An empty string could fail silently whereas a `null` value may fail loudly(exception) which is a good thing. (In this case `MessageBox.Show` would not throw an exception)

Comment: @Servy er, the for loop and the string usage in the original post IS shady. My point was simply assigning null to a string. Not really sure why you'll ever want a string with a null value - I consider it an exception waiting to happen. But that could be a matter of preference.

Comment: @Tyress The code here would function perfectly fine with `null`.  There are also plenty of situations in which having a `null` string is fine, normally where you want to make it clear that the value *shouldn't* be used until given a value, and that you *want* it to complain loudly if you are using the value inappropriately rather than silently continuing on despite being in an invalid state.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Pretty sure `MessageBox.Show` doesn't throw when passed a null string.

Comment: @Servy: ... as i've mentioned in the comment. I just wanted to note that it's more likely that you get an unexpected behaviour(f.e. exception) if you use `null` instead of an empty string which is a good thing (as opposed to Tyres  opinion). Using a wrong value is not the best way to handle unexpected behaviours.

Comment: Well, if the null value works for you, it works for you. I personally don't like it. Most of the time, a string.Empty is what you want to represent a null value too, especially if you're getting data from databases which you will need to coalesce with an empty string to display on some other medium outside of MessageBox.Show(), or write to a different data-interchange format. On those occasions it will complain, and it doesn't have to. As I said, it is preference. I _prefer_ to use a string.Empty.

Comment: If you want to _display_ something you often don't want to see `NULL`. But whether a `null` value  or an empty string is more appropriate as default value in general depends on the context. In most cases it is better to treat a currently not defined value as `null` instead of empty. The latter is a valid value. You're also not able anymore to differentiate between the unassigned  value and a value that is just empty. If you get a `NullReferenceException` it's a good thing, it helps to make the code more robust. An empty string is likely to fail silently (f.e the user gets incorrect result).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is I do not necessarily check the context anymore. I just go with string.Empty. Makes life simpler for me. You are correct with a loud NullReferenceException to make sure values are filled, but if I had critical data using strings,I would make other checks just so I don't have to use a string with a null assignent. Here's actually a question on this very topic, and I like the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689876/string-empty-vs-null-which-one-do-you-use .

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands does not compile, you can make it compile by, as Tim suggests, assigning `string drivenames = null`.

Your program will then display the *last* drive name as on each iteration, the previous value will be overridden by the previous and if you don't have any drives then null will be passed to `MessageBox.Show` which will at best show an empty text box, at worst throw a runtime exception.

Assuming you only want one message box to show, may I suggest the following change to your code:

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

IEnumerable<string> driveNames = drives.Select(drive => drive.Name);

string output = String.Join(", ", driveNames);

MessageBox.Show(output); // will display "C, D, E" or similar
```