# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid?' and 'string'

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I am getting this error in a `LINQ` query with the below code:

> "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid?' and 'string'"

I have a `nullable GUID object`, here I am checking if the `GUID Object` is `null`, then I need to `return` `String.Empty` else will be converting `GUID` to `string`

```
List<Report> queryresult =
    reportDatatable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(c => c.Field<Guid?>("ParentID") == Guid.Parse("XXXXXX-XXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX))
        .Select(c=> new Report()
        {
            ID = (c.Field<Guid?>("ID") ?? String.Empty).ToString(), //error here
            ...
        }).ToList();
```

Below link as simplest way to check whether `object` is `null` or not.

Suggest if any other approach to check `GUID object` is `null` or not

Comment: I don't see any C++ here, so you should remove the tag.

Comment: Great. Glad that the solution works well. :)

Comment: Please check hvd answer, you might find it the simplest. After you do, please uncheck my answer and check his - because I learn something new from him too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

Apparently, what suits your need best would be this:

```
ID = (c.Field<Guid?>("ID") ?? Guid.Empty) == Guid.Empty ? String.Empty : c.Field<Guid?>("ID").ToString(), //try this
```

---

**Original**

Convert your GUID to `string` first:

```
c.Field<Guid?>("ID").ToString() ?? String.Empty
```

Then it should be ok.

Else, use `Guid.Empty` instead of `String.Empty` the idea here is that both sides in `??` must match. Like comparing `Apple` to `Apple`

To prevent `c.Field<Guid?>("ID") == null` being executed, in C#6, you could make it more simply like this

```
c.Field<Guid?>("ID")?.ToString() ?? String.Empty
```

Comment: `ToString()` never returns `null`, making this not very useful.

Comment: If `c.Field<Guid?>("ID")` was null in the first place, calling a method on it isn't going to end well. You could replace the dot with `?.` to make this work.

Comment: Make that `c.Field<Guid?>("ID")?.ToString() ?? String.Empty` (if using C# 6)

Comment: @hvd String.Empty isn't null I think... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689876/string-empty-vs-null-which-one-do-you-use

Comment: @Ian, Nope, String.Empty isn't null, but `c.Field<Guid?>("ID")` might be

Comment: @Ian If the LHS of `??` is never `null`, the `??` operator doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HenrikIlgen ok, I updated the final answer according to the need. It seems like what OP wants involves **two** steps: (1) to check Guid, (2) To convert into `string`

Comment: Er... I meant something else. I meant that just `c.Field<Guid?>("ID").ToString()` would be enough. `((Guid?)null).ToString()` produces an empty string. :)

Comment: @hvd "`((Guid?)null).ToString()` produces an `Empty.String`" this is really new for me.. :s you should be the answerer, Sir. Not me... Or I should just put it but credit it to you/any of your answers? I think it is fairer that way... :s

Comment: Thanks :) Given your initial version of that last comment I started typing up an answer, and I didn't see your edit before I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `Nullable<>`'s `ToString()` override produces an empty string if the value is null, you can simply write

```
ID = c.Field<Guid?>("ID").ToString()
```

Depending on your reporting code, better yet could be to make `Report`'s `ID` of type `Guid?`, but that won't necessarily always work.

Comment: Ok, voted up. ;) I will tell the OP to uncheck my answer and check yours too. ;)

Comment: Ok, I already put up a comment in about your answer in the OP post, hope he will notice. ;) again thanks for the new stuffs I learn from you. ;) It just surprise me that nullable type, when the value is null can use `ToString()` method like that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `Guid.Empty` instead of `String.Empty` for `??` operator as left hand side is `Guid` not `string`. That is what the compiler error *"Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid?' and 'string'"* suggests.

```
 ID = (c.Field<Guid?>("ID") ?? Guid.Empty).ToString(),
```

**Edit**

If you want empty string then you can put condition to return empty string for Guid.Empty. Your query will end up with something like this.

```
ID = (c.Field<Guid?>("ID") ?? Guid.Empty) == Guid.Empty ? 
        String.Empty : c.Field<Guid?>("ID").ToString(),
```

Comment: This would return the empty GUID (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`) in case the field is null, which is not what OP needs to return: *if the GUID Object is null the i need to return String.Empty*

Comment: It required OP to adjust the code accordingly but he can return empty string, check updated answer. Thanks for pointing though.

Answer (score 0):

As you have nullable GUID, you can use HasValue to check if value exist

```
(c.Field<Guid?>("ID").HasValue ? c.Field<Guid?>("ID").Value:String.Empty).ToString()
```