# filter string empty value

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

how can i get string empty value got filter ?
as you can see when i click on empty string it wont got filter ! 
but when i click on null value it got filter.

[filter in name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auj7Z.png)

[filter in number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjkxT.png)

iam using same both code on column name and number

```
 RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox1 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
 RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox2 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
 private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
        string name= gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["name"].ToString();            
        if (!repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(name))
           {
           repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(name);
           }
        string number= gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["number"].ToString();            
        if (!repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Contains(number))
           {
           repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Add(number);
           }
        }
    }
```

in database name got empty value and number got null value. is there a problem with my code? how should i modify the code?
edited
iam adding this piece of code it gives me no where , still cant get it filter

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                string xa = "";
                if (!repositoryItemComboBox11.Items.Contains(xa))
                {
                    repositoryItemComboBox11.Items.Add(xa);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name= gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["name"].ToString();
```

You should not use `ToString` method directly. Because if the value is null, this will cause an exception.

Comment: there's no other option left. only got `to.string()`. what exception ?

Comment: NullReferenceException

Comment: You should take to determine whether the value is null。

Comment: but when i complie it, i got no null reference. its just i dont get to filter it.  what is empty and null  value ? from database type itself was diffrence

Comment: if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["name"]==null)
           {
           name="";
           }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689876/string-empty-vs-null-which-one-do-you-use

Comment: of course,i am not sure this is the problem。debug your code