# Regular expression of data annotation not working for empty strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I trying to validate string attribute in an object that created from data annotated model. This validation logic contains regular expression that checks whether the string is not empty or blank. Validation only fails when stringing with multiple spaces ("_________") it does not fail when attribute without space, that mean empty string("").

Annotated data model,

```
class Company
{
  [RegularExpression(@".*\S+.*$", ErrorMessage = "Website is empty")]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "website")]
  public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

Calling for validation,

```
Company company = new Company(){
     Website = ""
};
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var context = new ValidationContext(company, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
Validator.TryValidateObject(company, context, validationResults, true);
```

validationResults not capture the validation error.

Comment: Why don't you use the [Required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute? - it does what I think you're after -  _"A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters."_

Comment: .. although looking at your regex, it only seems to match strings containing non-space characters as well as spaces. Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: stuartd -> I need to invalidate model when an empty string and keep validate it when null value.

Comment: An 'empty string' and `null` are identical (as far as model binding is concerned) Its not clear what what you are wanting to validate

Comment: @Stephen Muecke https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689876/string-empty-vs-null-which-one-do-you-use are not the same.

Comment: My validation is simple I want to have an empty string and blank string should have a validation error and NULL values have to be not.

Comment: Read my comment carefully - the model binder reads the value from the request - there is no such thing as `null` - its just text. So again, they are  identical as far as model binding is concerned)