# How to remove first 10 characters from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, substring

How to ignore the first 10 characters of a string?

Input:

```
str = "hello world!";
```

Output:

```
d!
```

Comment: string.Substring(9); where 9 is start index

Comment: Remember to check first that the string has at least 10 chars or you will get an exception.

Comment: Why substring don't support (startIndex,endindex) ? every time we have to calculate Length.. :-(

Comment: @Waqas: actually it's str.Substring(10), the parameter being the position from which the substring starts to be extracted

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
str = "hello world!";
str.Substring(10, str.Length-10)
```

you will need to perform the length checks else this would throw an error

Comment: @DrorBar in C#, method names follow PascalCase. substring() won't compile because the method is called Substring()

Comment: @DavidKlempfner My bad I thought this is JavaScript.

Answer (score 268):

`str = str.Remove(0,10);` 
Removes the first 10 characters

or

`str = str.Substring(10);`
Creates a substring starting at the 11th character to the end of the string.

For your purposes they should work identically.

Answer (score 19):

Substring is probably what you want, as others pointed out. But just to add another option to the mix...

```
string result = string.Join(string.Empty, str.Skip(10));
```

You dont even need to check the length on this! :) If its less than 10 chars, you get an empty string.

Comment: And for better readability, you can use "". It compiles exactly the same as string.Empty these days.

Comment: It does not, "" creates a new string, while string.Empty references one. It doesn't really matter in terms of performance (I mean it's one empty string so yeah...) but just wanted to point that out :)

Comment: "" does indeed not create a new string, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/263257/604613

Answer (score 14):

`Substring` has two Overloading methods:

```
public string Substring(int startIndex);//The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

public string Substring(int startIndex, int length);//The substring starts at a specified character position and taking length no of character from the startIndex.
```

So for this scenario, you may use the first method like this below:

```
var str = "hello world!";
str = str.Substring(10);
```

Here the output is:

```
d!
```

If you may apply defensive coding by checking its length.

Answer (score 6):

The `Substring` has a parameter called startIndex. Set it according to the index you want to start at.

Answer (score 4):

You Can Remove Char using below Line ,

:- **First check That String has enough char to remove** ,like

```
   string temp="Hello Stack overflow";
   if(temp.Length>10)
   {
    string textIWant = temp.Remove(0, 10);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting from C# 8, you simply can use Range Operator. It's the more efficient and better way to handle such cases.

```
string AnString = "Hello World!";
AnString = AnString[10..];
```

Comment: `C# 8` is not supported when targeting `.NET Framework`.

Answer (score 3):

Use substring method.

```
string s = "hello world";
s=s.Substring(10, s.Length-10);
```

Comment: throws exception if string is shorter than starting index

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) method that takes a single parameter, which is the index to start from.

In my code below i deal with the case were the length is less than your desired start index and when the length is zero.

```
string s = "hello world!";
s = s.Substring(Math.Max(0, Math.Min(10, s.Length - 1)));
```

Comment: currently it returns the last character from the string if the string is less that 10 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
var str = "hello world!";
```

To get the resulting string without the first 10 characters and an empty string if the string is less or equal in length to 10 you can use:

```
var result = str.Length <= 10 ? "" : str.Substring(10);
```

or

```
var result = str.Length <= 10 ? "" : str.Remove(0, 10);
```

First variant being preferred since it needs only one method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify the length into the `Substring` method.
Therefore:

```
string s = hello world;
string p = s.Substring(3);
```

`p` will be:

> "lo world".

The only exception you need to cater for is `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if
`startIndex` is less than zero or greater than the length of this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `SubString()` allocates a new string. For optimal performance, you should avoid that extra allocation. Starting with `C# 7.2` you can take advantage of the [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay) pattern.

When targeting `.NET Framework`, include the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) `NuGet` package. For `.NET Core` projects this works out of the box.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "hello world!";
    var span = str.AsSpan(10); // No allocation!

    // Outputs: d!
    foreach (var c in span)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```