# C# substrings: Removing first three characters

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a string which I would like to remove the first three characters from. How do I go about this using substrings, or is there any other way?

```
string temp = "01_Barnsley"
string textIWant = "Barnsley"
```

Thank you

Comment: We need to start tagging questions like these as `frist-psot` (a la Slashdot) given the typo encrusted race to answer it results in. Mash it out then enter the edit frenzy!

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the first three characters? It seems to me that you're more interested in removing everything up to (and including) the first underscore.

Comment: That question is way too deep for SO. I mean, what _is_ Google?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove first 10 characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186648/how-to-remove-first-10-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`String.Substring(Int32)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring **starts at a
>   specified character position and continues to the end of the string.**

```
string textIWant = temp.Substring(3);
```

Here is a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/EvpyXe)</kbd>.

As an alternative, you can use [`String.Remove method(Int32, Int32)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also.

> Returns a new string in which a specified number of characters in the
>   current instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted.

```
string textIWant = temp.Remove(0, 3);
```

Here is a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/71acFK)</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe it was that simple. I knew how to get parts of strings but not remove beginning parts.

Comment: I did use Google but couldn't find the solution to this particular problem.

Comment: @Phil What did you wrote in Google exactly?

Answer (score 3):

you can use  [String.Substring Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string textIWant = temp.Substring(3);
```

or
[String.Remove Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string textIWant = temp.Remove(0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a pattern to the data, one can use that to extract out what is needed using Regular Expressions.

So if one knows there are numbers (`\d` regex for digits and with 1 or more with a `+`) followed by an under bar; that is the pattern to exclude. Now we tell the parser what we want *to capture* by saying we want a *group match* using `( )` notation. Within that sub group we say capture everything by using `.+`. The period (`.`) means *any character* and the `+` as seen before means 1 or more.

The full match for the whole pattern (not what we want) is grouped as at index zero. We want the first subgroup match at index 1 which is our data.

```
Console.WriteLine (Regex.Match("01_Barnsley",   @"\d+_(.+)").Groups[1].Value); // Barnsley
Console.WriteLine (Regex.Match("9999_Omegaman", @"\d+_(.+)").Groups[1].Value); // Omegaman
```

Notice how we don't have to worry if its more than two digits? Whereas substring can fail because the number grew, it is not a problem for the regex parser *due to the flexibility found in our pattern*.

### Summary

If there is a distinct pattern to the data, and the data may change, use regex. The minimal learning curve can pay off handsomely. If you truly just need something at a specific point that is unchanging, use substring.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using LINQ:

```
string temp = "01_Barnsley";
string textIWant = new string(temp.Skip(3).ToArray());
```