# easy way of removing char from a string?

Tags: c#

I have `string` like this:

```
string something = "12+3-1";
something.hereIwantToRemoveFirstElement();
Console.WriteLine(something); // i want to get "2+3-1"
```

Is it possible? Or maybe I should do like that to remove char from string, like it is in `List`?

```
something.RemoveAt(2);
Console.WriteLine(something);// i want to get "123-1"
```

Or maybe there is easy way to convert entire string to list, and then remove specific element?

```
something.ToList().
something.RemoveAt(0);// i want to get "2+3-1"
```

Can you please tell me how to do it efficiently?

Comment: Surely if you are using a `string`, and you use the already provided method `RemoveAt`, what is the issue?

Comment: `something.Substring(1)` will remove the first element. If you want to convert it to a list, `something.ToList()` will do it, then `string.Concat(something)` to turn it back into a string

Comment: `string` is immutable so you have to assign the result back like this `something = somthing.Remove(2);`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That there is no `String.RemoveAt()`

Comment: sadly when i click a '.' next to my string i only get Remove, not RemoveAt, and also i do not get ToList(), im working on visual studio, i shuld download some library for this?

Comment: @Maciek - `ToList` is a part of the `System.Linq` namespace, so just add a `using` declaration for that. Although I will say that would be an odd approach for such a simple string operation. Just use one of the built-in methods. Keep in mind that it's *always* a good idea to look through the docs to get an understanding of what these methods do and examples of proper usage.

Comment: @Maciek No, you don't have to download an additional library for that. Just look at the provided answers to this question. They will show some built-in possiblities how to solve your problem.

Comment: @derpirscher I gotcha. I guess he did not make that clear. His wording implied such a function. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There are many questions this could have been closed as a duplicate of: [Fastest way to remove first char in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3222125/215552); [How to remove first 10 characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7186648/215552) (since it would just be changing the number from 10 to 1), [C# substrings: Removing first three characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21909132/215552), etc.

Comment: not quite true, i also ask about removing random char, but never the less i found my answer here

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so you can't edit them in place, but you can create a new one without the first char

```
string something = "12+3-1";
string result = something.Substring(1);
```

You could also assign the result back to the same variable of course

```
string something = "12+3-1";
something = something.Substring(1);
```

You can also use the same method for concatenating 2 substrings from the original

```
string result = something.Substring(0,2) + something.Substring(3); // 123-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0) method which returns a new string in which a specified number of characters from the current string are deleted:

```cs
var startIndex = 2;
var count = 1;
Console.WriteLine("12+3-1".Remove(startIndex, count)); prints "123-1"
Console.WriteLine("12+3-1".Remove(0, count)); prints "2+3-1"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Remove` methode like this:

```
something = something.Remove(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two possibilites.

1. You use [`String.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0)

   ```
    var s = "1234";
    //removes 1 character at position 2
    s = s.Remove(2,1); 
    Console.WriteLine(s); //prints 124
   ```
2. You use [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

   ```
    var s = "1234";

    //takes a substring from index 0 and length 2 and 
    //concatenates it with a substring starting at index 3, 
    //thus effectifly removing one character at index 2
    s = s.Substring(0,2) + s.Substring(3);  

    Console.WriteLine(s); //prints 124
   ```