# String.Empty as a "precision specifier"

Tags: c#, string

[Jon Skeet said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or) that `""` and `String.Empty` are equivalent due to string interning.  In looking at MSDN for [ICustomFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) there is a line in the `Format` method

```
// Handle null or empty format string, string with precision specifier.
string thisFmt = String.Empty;
```

At first I thought they might be adding an empty string in order to avoid dealing with nulls in later logic.  But this doesn't explain what they mean by "precision specifier".

What is a "precision specifier"?

Comment: MSDN article  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: Comments lie, setting `thisFmt` to an empty string is just a safeguard for null checking as you already stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When formatting strings to number types a precision specifier can be supplied in the format string as in the following examples:

```
 int quantity = 1500;
 float price = 1.50F;
 float discount = 0.05F;

 Console.WriteLine(quantity.ToString("n0"));        // Outputs "1,500"
 Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("c"));            // Outputs "£1.50"
 Console.WriteLine(discount.ToString("p1"));        // Outputs "5.0 %"
```

In the case of the fixed point and percentage specifier a number is included. This is the precision specifier and is used to modify the format.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The precision specifier ranges from 0 to 99 and controls the number of
>   significant digits or zeros to the right of a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that later, this variable will contain a format string, which includes a precision specifier. I.e., if a double value is formatted, then you can specify how many digits to the right of the decimal point will be displayed. It is not linked to string internals.