# initialize multipile variables with different values (same as javascript)

Tags: c#, variables

i was searching if there's a way to initialize multiple variables  with **different** values on the same line, same as you can do in JavaScript.
(maybe in c# 6 ?)

for example:

```
var x = "hello", 
    y = "friend";
```

** EDIT

I know i can assign with the same value (seen other posts on SO as well - i don't see how this post is duplicated )
i would like it to be with different values (using the var key word).
as i see from the answers below i see there's no way without explicitly  declare the type.
so thanks for the help.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374454/declare-and-assign-multiple-string-variables-at-the-same-time

Comment: Oh sorry I must have used an older version where you couldn't use them in single line. Or maybe it was VB.NET Please ignore my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just assign like that:

```
string str = "1", str1="2", str3="3", str4="4", str5="5";
```

please, remember, that **implicitly-typed local variables cannot have multiple declarations**
**so  this code will not be compiled:**

```
var someVar1 = "1", someVar2 = "2", someVar3 = "3", someVar4 = "4", someVar5 = "5";//This line is error and is not compiled!
```

Answer (score 4):

Implicitly-typed variables cannot have multiple declarators. You have to specify the type.

```
string x = "hello", 
       y = "friend";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, but only if you don't use `var`:

```
string x = "hello", y = "friend";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String x = "hello", 
    y = "friend";
```

or

```
Object x = "hello", 
    y = "friend";
```

or

```
Object x = "hello", 
    y = 22.21;
```