# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property

Tags: c#

I have been programming for a few years, and I know, that the following should work perfectly fine. Just trying to initialize all variables with one common type and same value.

```
int count = 0, 
    xmin = count, 
    xmax = count,  
    ymin = count, 
    ymax = count;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```cs
int count, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = 0;
```

EDIT:

[image]

Your original code seems to work no?

EDIT2:

Well ofcourse that won't work in a field initializer!

> A field initializer cannot refer to other instance fields.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields

You can probs move the init code to your constructor if you really want - something like:

```cs
int count = 3, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

void MyCtor()
{
    xmin = xmax = ymin = ymax = count;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I found this syntax: `string a = "", b = a , c = a, d = a, e = a, f =a;` from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374454/declare-and-assign-multiple-string-variables-at-the-same-time

Comment: This old syntax that you are proposing works, I recall it now. But, I thought, the other one there would work too.

Comment: I get the following error in VS, **A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property**, with the original code.

Comment: @JohnSmith well it works on my machine - and so it does on others: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vCoo6o

Comment: Maybe some configuration in my Visual Studio, I am declaring and initializing this code inside a MainWindow.cs class

Comment: Sommmen, see my edit. Posted a printscreen.

Comment: @JohnSmith well you hadn't posted the actual code, anyway field initialzers can't be done the way you want you'd have to init them seperately.

Comment: Sommmen, thank you for your answer. Take care mate!

Comment: Sommmanen, just did that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assign same value to multiple variables in a single line could be done in the following way

```
int count, xmin , xmax ,  ymin , ymax;
count = xmin = xmax = ymin = yman = 0;
```

Or like this

```
int count, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = 0;
```

Comment: Ran, thank you for your input too!