# Difference between string.Empty and String.Empty in C#

Tags: c#, string

What is the difference between string.Empty and String.Empty in C#? Also note the colors are different. They both reference or are of type class System.String

[image]

Comment: Google would be a good way to find this difference very easily.  Or the search function here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or?rq=1

Comment: they are just the same.String is the actual class and the keyword string just maps to the class String

Answer (score 5):

It is the same. `string` is an **alias** of class `System.String`.

some common aliases:

```
object  ==>  System.Object
string  ==>  System.String
bool    ==>  System.Boolean
int     ==>  System.Int32
float   ==>  System.Single
double  ==>  System.Double
decimal ==>  System.Decimal
char    ==>  System.Char
```

Answer (score 4):

`String.Empty` and `string.Empty` are same. `String` is the BCL class name. `string` is the C#...shortcut if you will. Same as with Int32 and int.

Answer (score 2):

Both are ***SAME*** except that `string` is treated as a `keyword` with `Blue` color (default) and `System.String` is a `Class` with `Green` Color (default) in the VS editor.

Underlying implementation are all the same. In other words points to the same.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the string keyword is an alias for String. Therefore, String and string are equivalent, and you can use whichever naming convention you prefer. The String class provides many methods for safely creating, manipulating, and comparing strings. In addition, the C# language overloads some operators to simplify common string operations