# How to remove " [ ] \ from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string

I have a string

```
"[\"1,1\",\"2,2\"]"
```

and I want to turn this string onto this

```
1,1,2,2
```

I am using Replace function for that like

```
obj.str.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Replace("\\","");
```

But it does not return the expected result.
Please help.

Comment: what output does it give you because its seems fine

Comment: "not returns perfect answer" - please explain...

Comment: Is your input string JSON? Then better [use a JSON parser](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+parse+json). ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))

Comment: use `string.Empty` instead of `""`

Comment: @Jodrell Why? How would that help?

Comment: @Magnus, I'm just trying to impose style rules on the world. However I'm now considering the veracity of this rule.

Comment: [u can use linq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19001340/821057)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't removed the double quotes. Use the following:

```
obj.str = obj.str.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Replace("\\","").Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: use `string.Empty` instead of `""`

Comment: This will iterate 4 times instead of one.

Comment: @Jodrell: Why? It's more verbose. Even [Jon Skeet uses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/263257/284240) `""` ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, admittedly, its just a style thing, http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1122.html is it good to be consistent even if the underlying reasoning is flawed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an optimized approach in case the string  or the list of exclude-characters is long:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static String RemoveAll(this string input, params Char[] charactersToRemove)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || (charactersToRemove==null || charactersToRemove.Length==0))
            return input;

        var exclude = new HashSet<Char>(charactersToRemove); // removes duplicates and has constant lookup time
        var sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
        foreach (Char c in input)
        {
            if (!exclude.Contains(c))
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Use it in this way:

```
str = str.RemoveAll('"', '[', ']', '\\'); 
// or use a string as "remove-array":
string removeChars = "\"{[]\\";
str = str.RemoveAll(removeChars.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: since this essentially what I wrote, in response to your comment, +1

Comment: theres another style cop rule that says use (in effect) use `char` instead of `Char`.

Comment: @Jodrell: I have a feeling that Jon Skeet doesn't use style cop  ;-) [_" I use the aliases everywhere for the implementation"_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/284240) I personally also don't use the uppercase class names for the classes with aliases just because i'm lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You should do following:

```
obj.str = obj.str.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Replace("\"","");
```

---

`string.Replace` method does not replace string content in place. This means that if you have
string test = "12345" and do

```
test.Replace("2", "1");
```

test string will still be `"12345"`. Replace doesn't change string itself, but creates new string with replaced content. So you need to assign this new string to a new or same variable

```
changedTest = test.Replace("2", "1");
```

Now, `changedTest` will containt `"11345"`.

Another note on your code is that you don't actually have \ character in your string. It's only displayed in order to *escape* quote character. If you want to know more about this, please [read MSDN article on string literals.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
var exclusions = new HashSet<char>(new[] { '"', '[', ']', '\\' });
return new string(obj.str.Where(c => !exclusions.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

To do it all in one sweep.

As Tim Schmelter writes, if you wanted to do it often, especially with large exclusion sets over long strings, you could make an extension like this.

```
public static string Strip(
        this string  source,
        params char[] exclusions)
{
    if (!exclusions.Any())
    {
        return source;
    }

    var mask = new HashSet<char>(exclusions);
    var result = new StringBuilder(source.Length);
    foreach (var c in source.Where(c => !mask.Contains(c)))
    {
        result.Append(c);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

so you could do,

```
var result = "[\"1,1\",\"2,2\"]".Strip('"', '[', ']', '\\');
```

Comment: `Except` uses a set and removes all repeating characters from both sequences, hence the resulting array does not contain duplicate characters which is probably not desired. If you want to avoid multiple `Replaces` the best way is to use a loop and a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Should work (if you change it to `...new []{...`). But i doubt that it's more efficient at all because of the `ToArray()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, damn typos.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the numbers only with this regular expression `[0-9]+` and then concatenate the matches:

```
var input = "[\"1,1\",\"2,2\"]";
var regex = new Regex("[0-9]+");
var matches = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
var result = string.Join(",", matches);
```