# How can I convert a nullable TimeSpan to a string with a specific format?

Tags: c#, timespan

I need to convert a `TimeSpan` to a string with the format `hh:mm tt`.

```
Timespan? tTime;
Console.WriteLine(tTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
```

`ToString("hh:mm tt")` works well if value is not null, but its causes an error when the value is null.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting an error is because `tTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")` tries to forcibly convert its value to a string, with the required format.
If that value is null, there is no way for the conversion to handle it, thus throwing an error.

One way to do it is by following @KevinCloet's answer, where he simply checks if the `tTime` has a value, and converts it if it does.

```
//                validation     ? if true                          : if false
Console.WriteLine(tTime.HasValue ? tTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") : String.Empty);
```

which could also be written as:

```
// Boolean values don't need = true
if(tTime.HasValue){
   Console.WriteLine(tTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
}else{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
}
```

Another way to do it is through a `try{}catch(){}` method, which is almost the same as the extended `if` statement

```
try{
   Console.WriteLine(tTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
}
catch(Exception e){
   // You don't actually need the 'Exception e', 
   // however 'e.Message' will tell you exactly what went wrong
   Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
}
```

I hope this explanation will help you understand, rather than just give you an answer.

**Edit:**
Based on [Jon Skeets answer on "" vs String.Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or), you can essentially use either.

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be used for your normal flow. [ref 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control), [ref 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception). The fact that the variable is nullable indicates that it's *normal* to have a null value.

Comment: @Stijn excellent point out. I was merely showing that theres more than one way to solve an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an if statement or the shortened ? statement. Fill in your desired result in `: ""`  when the value is null

```
Console.WriteLine(tTime.HasValue ? tTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") : "");
```

Comment: Got flagged for length+content, presumably because of no explanation.

Comment: Well the question is very simple, as is the answer. Still made a simple explanation

Comment: I believe it should be `tTime.Value.ToString(...)`

Comment: Drop the useless `== true`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check for a value first, by using `HasValue`, or by comparing with null.

However, you also need to use a valid [timespan format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).  `"hh:mm tt"` is valid on `DateTime`, but not on `TimeSpan`.  Try this:

```
string s = tTime.HasValue ? tTime.Value.ToString("hh\\:mm") : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
string time = spantime.HasValue ? spantime.Value.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss") : "??:??:??";
```