# How to return empty string if an object is null?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, null

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var link = socials.Where(p => p.type == Facebook).FirstOrDefault().URL;
```

the problem is that there aren't any social object in the list, `FirstOrDefault()` return `null`, and `.URL` trigger an exception.

How can I avoid this in "one" line with LINQ? Thus, if null return empty `""` (or custom even better) string, else `.URL`?

Comment: you can use .First();

Comment: @SirwanAfifi: which causes an exception if there is no type==facebook.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) with an argument to specify the fallback value:

```
var link = socials
    .Where(p => p.type == Facebook)
    .Select(p => p.Url)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("")
    .First();
```

`FirstOrDefault` is not necessary anymore, it is safe to use `First` with `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: But DefaultIfEmpty works even if the Select return 0 object? I mean, if the where count is 0, it returns at least one ""?

Comment: Yes, that's the sole purpose of `DefaultIfEmpty`. It comes only into play if the sequence contains no elements. Then it uses the default value of the type or - if you use the overload as in my answer - it uses the value provided. So with the same result as if the sequence contained only one element with that value.

Comment: Saved few additional lines of code and time. Works as expected

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to use null coalesce operator

```
var link = (socials
    .Where(p => p.type == Facebook)
    .Select(p => p.Url)
    .FirstOrDefault()) ?? string.empty;
```

I understood that `string.empty` is preferred over `""` but that may not be the case - see comment below.

**UPDATE**
In C# 6 there is a null conditional operator (also known as the "Elvis" operator):

```
var link = socials
    .Where(p => p.type == Facebook)
    .Select(p => p.Url)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.URL ?? string.empty;
```

A simple example:

```
stringbuilder sb = null;
// do work
string s = sb?.ToString() ?? "no values found";
```

Comment: Why is `string.empty` preferred over `""`? Tha's just a matter of personal preferences. Imo `""` is very clear.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between yours and mine answer. You get `String.Empty` if there is no `type==facebook` and also if the first matching `Url` is `null`. [My approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32138070/284240) still yields `null` in that case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Answer (score 6):

Using C# 6 you can use a [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) (`?.`) to return the URL if the object returned from the LINQ statement isn't `null`, i.e. if a value was found, or `null` otherwsie.

```
var link = socials.Where(p => p.type == Facebook).FirstOrDefault()?.URL;
```

If you then want to change a `null` value to an empty string or a custom string  then use the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`??`).

```
var link = socials.Where(p => p.type == Facebook).FirstOrDefault()?.URL ?? "No URL";
```

It should be noted that this won't make any distinction between whether an object wasn't found or an object was found but had a `null` URL value.