# How to convert a nullable datetime value to string.empty when datetime is null?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, conditional-operator

I'm reading back a nullable `DateTime?` property then assigning that value to a string property in short date format.

I can convert the date time value to a short date string and assign to the `IT_Date_String` property. But I'm not sure how to assign a `""` value to the string if the `IT_Date` is null.

How can you convert a datetime? value to string.empty when datetime? is null?

This is the assignment in linq:

```
var status_list = query_all.ToList().Select(r => new RelStatus
{
    IT_Date_String = r.IT_Date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") != null ? r.IT_Date.Value : null
}).ToList();
```

And the properties in the model:

```
public DateTime? IT_Date { get; set; }
public string IT_Date_String { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're calling the `IT_Date.Value.ToString(...)` regardless of whether `IT_Date` actually has a value.

So you need to turn the expression around:

```
r.IT_Date.HasValue ? r.IT_Date.Value.ToString(...) : ""
```

This way `ToString()` will only be called when `IT_Date` has a value.

You can also implement this in the getter, as mentioned in a now-deleted comment:

```
public string IT_Date_String 
{ 
    get
    {
        return IT_Date.HasValue ? IT_Date.Value.ToString(...) : "";
    }
}
```

This way you won't have to reimplement the logic everywhere you access this model, and as a bonus, it will only be executed when it's actually requested.

There's also [no need to explicitly use `String.Empty`, the string `""` will be interned to the same at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or).

Comment: I like the idea of injecting the conversion into the model property. But when I did that the assignment tells me `IT_Date_String ` is read only. Do I need to add a setter also to that string property?

Comment: Like: `IT_Date_String = r.IT_Date` says that assignment is read only.

Comment: If you want to be able to set a date by assigning a string to the `IT_Date_String` property, then yes, you also need a setter that converts the string to a DateTime and assigns that to the `IT_Date` property.

Answer (score 8):

In C# 6 you can do this:

```
IT_Date_String = r.IT_Date?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ?? String.Empty;
```

The new `?` checks if the thing on the left is null, if it is, the expression evaluates to `null`. If not, it just continues the evaluation.

Then, `??` checks whether the result of the first expression is `null`, which it would be if `IT_Date` is null. If it is, evaluate to `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 3):

With C# 6.0 and null propagation you can use:

```
IT_Date_String = r.IT_Date?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ?? String.Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will work in any version of the framework:

```
IT_Date_String=string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",IT_Date);
```

Comment: True, though `yyyy-MM-dd` might be more valid, at least using common sense understanding of date/time tracking. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, I have corrected my answer. Probably it will be better to use CultureInfo instead of raw pattern, but that was out of the question scope