# String Literals and GC?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Let's assume that you have a string variable.

```
var t = "this is a test"
```

and we reassign another string to this variable

```
t = "this is another test"
```

what exactly happens with the data of the first assignment?
how does the framework handle this in relation to GC?

Comment: the first allocated string will be collected (asuming that exact text isn't used as another string somewhere else)

Comment: @HenkHolterman i am exactly asking about strings (interning), so the question is not too broad and probably not too beginner since you are unsure yourself. I have to modify the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String Literals are stored in the **String Intern Pool** and follow a different managing procedure than any other object which is regularly collected by the CG.

It then really comes down on how the String Intern Pool will manage the "this is a test" literal.

Most likely is that it won't be cleared and stay in the literal pool. But for more reference on how the String literal pools works below .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

http://dailydotnettips.com/2012/02/12/the-string-intern-pool/

[In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or "" to intitialize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or-to-intitialize-a-string)

Comment: The GC doesn't handle them separately, the strings are simply stored in a data structure in a rooted location.  From the GC's perspective they're simply always active; just like any other object(s) you store in a variable.  The GC doesn't have any sort of special knowledge of interned strings.