# Using c# NULL coalescing operator with NOT NULL Scenarios

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

I am populating a Class using LINQ and LinkUrl is a string property of my class.I need to set a value only if a property is not null , other wise no need to assign any values
Currently The conditional operator ?: is used

```
    var formattedData = dataset.Select(p => new  ListModel
    {
        Prop1=....,
        Prop2=....,
        ...
        LinkUrl = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.LabelUrl) ? "" : "SET MY PROPERRTY TO A VALUE",
        .....
    }).ToList();
```

Can we replace this with C#‘s null-coalescing operator (??)  or (?.) or something similar ??

Tne intention is to avoid the repeated use of assigning to "" in so many places

I can write it with operator ?? , but handle cases of NULL only  like below .

```
    LinkUrl = p.LabelUrl ?? "SET MY PROPERRTY TO A VALUE"
```

Can we do something similar for Not null cases

Comment: If you use `string.Empty` instead of `""`, you never need to worry about assigning an empty string - it's free. The compiler always assigns the same instance, so that you don't waste any memory at all.

Comment: @PMF Strings are interned in C#, so assigning `""` also reuses the same instance.

Comment: It appears you are right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or-to-intitialize-a-string I wasn't sure about this.

Comment: My intention in asking this question is  to check any new features  in c# available like ?? or ?. to replace the need of writing the logic on one side which is not necessary in this case . Looks like if we use ?: it is mandatory to  write the logic for both if and else cases

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want... if `p.LabelUrl` is null, your current code will replace it with `""`, but you say that you "need to set a value only if a property is not null" - which contradicts what your example code is actually doing.

Comment: I want to set a string property  LinkUrl only if p.LabelUrl is NOT NULL.  Looks like if we use ?: it is mandatory to write the logic for both if and else cases  In my case it is not really necessary to write the "" part

Comment: So you're actually looking for a shorthand for `if (LinkUrl != null) LinkUrl = "SET MY PROPERRTY TO A VALUE";` ? Or do you also need to handle the case that `LinkUrl` is not null but is whitespace (in which case set it to `""`)?

Comment: Looking for a shorthand of   if(p.LabelUrl !=null) LinkUrl = "SET MY PROPERRTY TO A VALUE";

Answer (score 1):

I think closest you could get to a shorthand for not null would be a set of extension methods

```
    public static T NullOrValue<T>(this T nullable, T value) where T : class => nullable == null ? null : value;
    
    public static T? NullOrValue<T>(this T? nullable, T value) where T : struct => nullable == null ? (T?)null : value;
```

Which would then be available on any nullable object as

```
var value = anyObjectOrNullable.NullOrValue(MyValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [Null-coalescing assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment).

But it won't check for empty strings.

Comment: Key req for me is to check the empty strings and i have to perform the actions only if the string is not empty

Comment: Then, it has nothing to do with null coalescing, right?

Comment: And you cannot conditionally assign in object initializers.