# There's an error when i try to return a String

Tags: java

I'm setting up a method to convert int month input by user into String, but can't seem to return the String.

**Error shows**

> Variable monthString might not have been initialized

```
public String StringMonth()
    {
       String monthString;
       switch (month)
    {
        case 1: monthString = "January";
        break;
        case 2: monthString = "February";
        break;
        case 3: monthString = "March";
        break;
        case 4: monthString = "April";
        break;
        case 5: monthString = "May";
        break;
        case 6: monthString = "June";
        break;
        case 7: monthString = "July";
        break;
        case 8: monthString = "August";
        break;
        case 9: monthString = "September";
        break;
        case 10: monthString = "October";
        break;
        case 11: monthString = "November";
        break;
        case 12: monthString = "December";
        break;
    }
       return monthString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, initialize it with a value.

Comment: There is a trace through your program where `monthString` is still not initialized, namely the **default case**, i.e. if none of the cases matched. Either provide a default-case or initialize it right away. Since the default case should in practice never trigger, do `default : throw new AssertionError();` or a different error/exception, depending on your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

This would do the trick:

```
public String StringMonth()
{
   String monthString = null;
   switch (month)
...
```

You may also wish to have a `default` case. And consider error handling when assigning a default value; what should happen?

Answer (score 1):

To fix simply do `String monthString = null;` or even better do `String monthString = StringUtils.EMPTY;`

**Initializing** a variable means assigning a variable an initial value before it ever gets used. If the variable has been declared but not **Initialized** then you will get the error message:

> Variable ***** might not have been initialized

So in your case you are getting this error because you just have `String monthString`, and you don't **initialize** `monthString` with an initial value resulting in the error message.

I prefer `String monthString = StringUtils.EMPTY` over `String monthString = null` just because we are assigning it an actual `string` value and not just `null`.

This is an interesting topic about [is StringUtils.EMPTY recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095501/is-stringutils-empty-recommended) albeit, it goes against what I'm suggesting about using `StringUtils.EMPTY` but I believe this makes it clear (that's just my opinion, not saying I'm right).