# How to fix "Refactor this code to use a "static final" Pattern" when replaceAll and replaceFirst methods are used

Tags: java, sonarqube

For the code below code, a hint is shown in sonar:

> Refactor this code to use a "static final" Pattern.

I don't understand, what the issue is. It is not clearly explained in sonar, either.

Please help me.

```
public Boolean validateLabelText(String labelValue, String fieldCell) {
        return labelValue
               .replaceAll(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY)
               .equalsIgnoreCase(fieldCell.replaceAll(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY)
                                          .replaceFirst(StringUtils.LF, StringUtils.EMPTY));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

> Refactor this code to use a "static final" Pattern.

You hit the following issue: [Regex patterns should not be created needlessly](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4248).

The problem is caused by these operations:

```
.replaceAll(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY)
```

```
.replaceFirst(StringUtils.LF, StringUtils.EMPTY)
```

Both methods create new instances of the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class. It means that when your method is executed 100 times, then your code creates 300 `Pattern` objects. The rule informs that you shouldn't do this, because `Pattern` are heavy objects and you can use more efficient code.

If `StringUtils` is `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` then the solution is as follow.

In the first operation

```
.replaceAll(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY)
```

you want to replace all occurrences of `" "` (space) by `""` (empty). This code should be changed to:

```
.replace(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY)
```

The `replace` method replaces literals as is. `replaceAll` treats the first parameter as regular expressions. There is no sense to parse a space character as a regular expression, because the output will be exactly the same.

Next in

```
.replaceFirst(StringUtils.LF, StringUtils.EMPTY)
```

you always create a new `Pattern` object from `StringUtils.LF`. Instead of creating a new pattern every time, you should compile it once and next reuse it:

```
private static final Pattern LF_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(StringUtils.LF, Pattern.LITERAL);
```

```
LF_PATTERN.matcher(string).replaceFirst(replacement);
```

The final code should be as follow:

```
private static final Pattern LF_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(StringUtils.LF, Pattern.LITERAL);

public Boolean validateLabelText(String labelValue, String fieldCell) {
    String value1 = labelValue.replace(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY);

    String value2 = fieldCell.replace(StringUtils.SPACE, StringUtils.EMPTY);
    value2 = LF_PATTERN.matcher(value2).replaceFirst(StringUtils.EMPTY);

    return value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2);
}
```

I don't know what is the business logic of your code, so I named variables as `value1` and `value2` (I don't know which value is `current` and which `expected`).

Answer (score 0):

rustyx ist right. The method could be made `static final`. I think, this is the cause of the sonar message. Also consider these three points.

`replaceAll` has a regular expression as its first parameter, but you do not need a regular expression here. You can use `replace` here. Use of regular expressions can reduce the performance, they are relatively slow.

Consider to use `boolean` as the return type. Using `Boolean` for a method that does a test is often bad style, because the caller has to check the return value for `null` also. There is rarely a need for a boolean to have a null value. When you use `boolean`, you say to the caller that the return value cannot be `null` and has not to be checked for that value. Using `Boolean` can also be slower than using `boolean` because of boxing/unboxing.

Btw: Do not use `StringUtils.EMPTY`. This constant is normally useless and only bloating the code. You can read this question and answers on the topic: [Is StringUtils.EMPTY recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095501/is-stringutils-empty-recommended) .

The performance issues (number 1 and 2) may not be really a problem, depending on the application and how often the method will be called.